# python how to remove http from a string using replace

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to remove "http://" in a string that contains a web URL i.e: "http://www.google.com". My code is:

```
import os
s = 'http://www.google.com'
s.replace("http://","")
print s
```

I try to replace http:// with a space but somehow it still prints out http://www.google.com

Am i using replace incorrectly here? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: even you can try : s.split('//')[1:] or s[7:]

Answer (score 19):

Strings are immutable. That means none of their methods *change* the existing string - rather, they give you back a new one. So, you need to assign the result back to a variable (the same, or a different, one):

```
s = 'http://www.google.com'
s = s.replace("http://","")
print s
```